# Agregar datos obtenidos mysqli a un array multi

Tags: php, mysql, array

estoy intentando agregar los datos obtenidos de un select y ordernarlos a un array en PHP.

Deseo acomodar de esta forma el array:

```
$array = array(noticias => array("1" => array ("titulo" => "Noticia 1", "autor" => "Pepe", "fecha" => "03/08/2018", "contenido" => "<b>Hola Mundo</b><br>")));
```

Este es mi código, hasta el momento solo obtengo el último registro de esta forma.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT 2";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$datos_acomodados = array("titulo" => $row['titulo'], "autor" => $row['autor'], "fecha" => $row['fecha'], "contenido" => $row['contenido']);
    //echo $row['titulo'];
    //echo $row['autor'];
    //echo $row['fecha'];
    //echo $row['contenido'];
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Tengo esta duda y también en la forma que la estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas declarar la variable `$datos_acomodados` como un array.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT 2";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$datos_acomodados = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$datos_acomodados[] = array("titulo" => $row['titulo'], "autor" => $row['autor'], "fecha" => $row['fecha'], "contenido" => $row['contenido']);
    //echo $row['titulo'];
    //echo $row['autor'];
    //echo $row['fecha'];
    //echo $row['contenido'];
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me di cuenta en declarar la variable afuera del while.

Comment: Realmente no hace falta declararla fuera del while, simplemente con añadir los corchetes a la variable dentro del while es suficiente